# Why is du giving me unexpected output?

Tags: disk-usage

I'm new to Linux, so sorry for my simple question. I'm on Ubuntu.

I have this directory:

```
$ ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 alberto alberto 4096 2011-04-03 16:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 alberto alberto 4096 2011-04-03 16:01 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 alberto alberto    7 2011-04-03 16:02 .hidden
-rw-r--r-- 1 alberto alberto    4 2011-04-03 15:51 testfile
```

When I run `du`, I'm expecting this:

```
$ du
4   testfile
4   .hidden
```

But I'm getting this:

```
$ du
12  .
$ du *
4   testfile
$ du .*
12  .
20  ../snippet
12  ../test
52  ..
4   .hidden
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: As an extra thing to consider, commands never see shell globs like * unless quoted. Shell expands it and passes the results to the command. So `du *` turns into `du testfile` and `du .*` turns into `du . .. .hidden`. This is why * always works and always works in the same way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`du` summarizes the disk usage directory by directory. In your example, since the current directory has no subdirectory, the output is a single line.

If you pass the name of a file on the command line, its size is reported. If you pass the names of multiple files, this is equivalent¹ to running `du` multiple times; hence `du .*` is equivalent to `du .; du ..; du .hidden`.

Run `du -a` to see the space occupied by each file.

```
 $ du -a
 4   .hidden
 4   testfile
 12  .
```

¹ 
<sub>Almost: on some systems, if a regular file has multiple hard links, then it's only counted the first time it's reached in a particular `du` invocation.</sub>

Comment: The second sentence of your second paragraph is not true. If files `foo` and `bar` are hardlinks to the same file, then `du foo bar`, `du bar foo` and `du foo; du bar` will each output something different.

Comment: @Steven: Yes, you're right, I wanted to keep things simple. Not all implementations do that, though. With GNU, `du foo bar` counts the file only once, but OpenBSD counts it twice. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/du.html) favors the GNU behavior, but I don't find it very clear on the case of multiple command line arguments.